# How can I remove the images but not the texts from the Ditto clipboard history?

Tags: windows, clipboard, history, ditto

I use Ditto on Windows. My ditto history file is over 100 GB:

[image]

I'd like to reduce its size.
How can I remove the images but not the texts from the Ditto clipboard history?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One can click on `Delete Clip Data`:

[image]

This shows the clipboard history with clip sizes and format:

[image]

Select `CF_DIB` to only list images and click on `Search`:

[image]

From https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dataxchg/standard-clipboard-formats:

> [CF_DIB is a] memory object containing a BITMAPINFO structure followed by the bitmap bits.